# How to position form's close button on right side?

Tags: forms, ms-access, ms-access-2016

On an old MS Access 2016 app, I remember that the close button was on the right side of the form's title bar.

Form being maximized the close button was on the right side of the app:

[image]

Now I have noticed that my close button is imediately after the form's name, so way off the right side:

[image]

Is there a way to configure this title bar and close button position or is an update of Access that changed this behaviour?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. This is a part of the design changes enforced in the latest update.

The reason is, that this design - where you also can reposition tabs - is more in line with what users see elsewhere.

You could, of course, add your own close button at the far right by setting its property Anchor to: Right.

Comment: Unfortunately, it seems you were right. I found some more info on Microsoft site: [February 5, 2019, update for Access 2016 (KB4032257)](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4032257/february-5-2019-update-for-access-2016-kb4032257) and they make a difference, as usual between Office 365 and the "rest" in here: [Show or hide object tabs](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/show-or-hide-object-tabs-25074ab7-bcc8-466d-81aa-b6cf739715cb#ID0EAADAAA=Office_365)